# Multiple state changes

Tags: reactjs

I am following a lesson. I have a controlled form and a handleInput method to reflect any changes in input. However, I didn't understand why he writes `[name]` instead of `name` inside of the handleInput method. A detailed explanation will be appreciated.

```
 handleInput(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        })
    }
```

Form Structure:

```
<Form>
    <FormGroup>
        <Label htmlFor="firstname" md={2}>First Name</Label>
        <Input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" 
                                value={this.state.firstname} 
                                onChange={this.handleInput} />

    </FormGroup>
    <FormGroup>
        <Label htmlFor="lastname" md={2}>Last Name</Label>
        <Input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" 
                                value={this.state.lastname} 
                                onChange={this.handleInput} />
    </FormGroup>
</Form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is for [`computed property name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

Its a new `ES6` feature which computed the property name of the object.

Before this you had to specify the property directly on the object.

```
var data = {};
data[name] = value;

this.setState(data);
```

With the new syntax you can do it inline with the object definition.

```
this.setState({
  [name]: value
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In the form, the input elements has names. In handleInput function, when you do

```
const name = target.name;
```

This name gets assigned to `name`

Now, on doing

```
this.setState({
        [name]: value
})
```

name gets evaluated to `firstname` or `lastname`.

You can read more about this feature [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Answer (score 1):

It's an ES6 feature, the square brackets allows you to programmatically reference the property of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the key in state as just `name: value` would reference an object key in state actually named `name`. Instead using `[name]` references the `value` of name attained from the input (`const name = target.name;`) which will in turn reference the corresponding key in the state.

Answer (score 0):

```
handleInput(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;
        // let name now = "blocker" and value = "something"
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        })
    }
```

on `console.log(this.state)
output will be`

```
{blocker:something}
```

Now if you remove [] from name

```
this.setState({
        name: value
    })
```

then on `console.log(this.state)`
output will be

```
{name:something}
```